# React Native, there is no route defined for index undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I want to create an Order Page with two tabs place order tab, my orders tab. So I have created one `Order.js` file and another `OrderContent.js` file.

`Order.js`

```
/* @flow */
import React from 'react'

import {
  View,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native'

import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

import HomeHeader from '../Components/HomeHeader'
import OrderContent from './OrderContent'


export default class OrdersScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawer: () => ({
      label: 'Orders',
    }),
  }
  static propTypes = {
    navigation: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
        <StatusBar
          barStyle="light-content"
          backgroundColor={'#202930'} />
        <HomeHeader
          title="Order Page"
          navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        <OrderContent navigation={this.props.navigation}
           />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

`Ordercontent.js`

```
const CustomTabView = ({router, navigation}) => {
  const { routes, index } = navigation.state
  const ActiveScreen = router.getComponentForState(navigation.state)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomTabBar navigation={navigation} />
      <ActiveScreen
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
          ...navigation,
          state: routes[index],
        })}/>
    </View>
  )
}
CustomTabView.propTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  navigation: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  // team: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

const CustomTabRouter = TabRouter({
    PlaceOrder: {
      screen: PlaceOrderScreen,
      path: '/place-order',
    },
    MyOrders: {
      screen: MyOrderScreen,
      path: '/my-orders',
    },
  },
  {
    // Change this to start on a different tab
    initialRouteName: 'PlaceOrder',
  }
)

const OrderContent = createNavigationContainer(createNavigator(CustomTabRouter)(CustomTabView))

export default OrderContent
```

When I tried to run the app, it shows like

> there is no route defined for the index undefined. Check that you passed in a navigation state with a valid tab index.

I know that the problem exists in `<OrderContent navigation={this.props.navigation} />` part itself but don't know how to overcome.

Comment: which routing library are you using?

Comment: react navigation library

Comment: Have you tried logging `index` or `navigation.state` in `CustomTabView`?

Comment: Can you post all the code of your highest component / application file?

Comment: The error is mainly because of the ActiveScreen tag expect `team` attribute. After I uncommenting the team line from `CustomTabView.propTypes` and adding the third `team` argument in `CustomTabView`, the error was gone. But I face another error `undefined is not an object on calling splashscreen.hide()`

Comment: Open issue: [undefined is not an object on calling hide()](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/30)

Comment: Third step: [configuration](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen#third-stepplugin-configuration)

Comment: doesn't that error means that you don't have a correct configuration of the routes. Missing the `root` route?

Comment: I believe that @matiasfh is right!

Comment: Make sure you have run this command `rnpm link react-native-splash-screen`, which should link the library automatically. In my case this worked for iOS but I had to do the manual linking for Android, which is described [here](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen#manual-installation)

Comment: You are trying to read a index that does not exsit. routes[index]  try reading index value and routes array, it should point you to the right direction.

Comment: which version are you using? (react and react route)

Answer (score 1):

react native by default goes to a page called index.js 
Have you created a file in this name ? 
it should contain something like this

```
<code>

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
</code>
```

Instead of App you can place Order or OrderContent instead .
Basically you choose your " landing tab " this way .